# Subscribe to multiple Observables in a loop in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following issue:

I have to loop through an array of objects (orders). For each order i do some processing, which is not relevant for now. Then i have to make multiple API calls for each order i.e. for each product of order.products i need to make an API call. Only when all of the calls have finished i can go on with processing some more things on my order. It is crucial that the processing can only take place when all of the calls have finished.

Here is what i was doing:

```
partial_orders.forEach(order => {
    //Do some processing on order...

    //Prepare the api calls:
    let calls = [];
    order.products.forEach(product => {
      calls.push(this.api.getProductByProductId(product.product_id));
    })

    let reorder_products = [];
    forkJoin(calls).subscribe(data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < calls.length; i++) {
        //Do some processing on the data that i caught...
        //...
        reorder_products.push(data[i]);
      }

      //Go on with some processing on order object based on the data i caught...
    })
  })
```

This is the API call function (returns Observable<any[]>)

```
public getProductByProductId(id) {
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(environment.apiUrl + '/api/product/' + id);
}
```

Apparently my code doesn't work. It seems like the loop goes on without waiting for the results of the forkJoin. So the next order element is already processed while the API calls for the previous one are still processing. However, it is crucial for me to only go to the next order object of my partial_orders when all API calls for an element have finished.

I am currently working with Angular 15.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem right, you want to process the orders one after the other.

If this is the case, your code actually does not do what you want. In fact it launches the execution, in parallel, of all `forkJoin`s for all orders.

A possible solution could be along these lines

```
// let's assume for clarity that we have a function that returns the forkJoin
// without subscription but after having done the processing relevant for
// each order, i.e. a function that returns an Observable
function productsFromIds(order) {
    let calls = [];
    order.products.forEach(product => {
      calls.push(this.api.getProductByProductId(product.product_id));
    })
    return forkJoin(calls).pipe(
        map(resultOfForkJoin => {
           //Do some processing on the data that i caught...
           //...
           return whateverCalculatedInTheProcessing
        })
    )
}
```

Then we proceed like this

```
let reorder_products = [];
// first you turn the array partial_orders into a stream of orders
// using the from function of rxJs
from(partial_orders).pipe(
   // then, for each order notified by the stream you concatenate
   // the "execution" of the forkJoin returned by the productsFromIds 
   // function using the concatMap operator
   concatMap(order => {
      return productsFromIds(order)
   }),
   // in this way you have transformed the stream of orders into a stream
   // of results of the forkJoins and the subsequent processing for each order
)
// now we can subscribe to get the stream of array and do whatever we need to do
.subscribe(resultsOfProcessingForEachOrder => {
   reorder_products.push(data[i]);
})
```